# Is a closed n-dimensional disk compact necessarily compact?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, soft-question

As the title asks, is a closed n-dimensional disk compact necessarily compact? I'm thinking the answer would be no. If you consider the case in $\mathbb{R}^1$ then can you define the radius to be infinite. As such you would get all of $\mathbb{R}$, which is both closed, but not compact (since it isn't bounded). The same construction can be applied for $\mathbb{R}^n$ by taking an infinite radius. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: A disk has finite radius.

Comment: What is a *closed n-dimensional disk compact*?

Comment: I think the first 'compact' is superfluous, and the first line should read '...is a closed n-dimensional disk necessarily compact?' Also (I don't know if the comments are the right place to discuss this), this user has asked a valid question, and demonstrated some thought and reasoning toward answering it themselves (even if the reasoning is flawed), so it's a little disappointing to see people downvoting it.

Comment: I upvoted to make up for an apparent downvote.  I see nothing wrong with the question, other than using the word "compact" twice, which looks like a typo, and not knowing the convention/definition that a disk has finite radius.  After all, a real interval can have infinite "radius".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AndréNicolas points out, a disk necessarily has finite radius.

It is true by the Heine-Borel theorem that, in the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, and therefore every closed disk is compact.

If you want a good exercise, try proving the Heine-Borel theorem on your own. If you get stuck, you can check wikipedia or an entry-level analysis or topology text for hints/an outline.